# Access to undefined property itemRenderer (Keyboard Event)

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flash-builder, itemrenderer

I am trying to get the following code to run when I hit enter on a row within a data grid, it works when I click on the row (ListEvent) but how would I enable this to work when the enter key is hit (KeyboardEvent). I have the enter key working although it throws this error every time

```
  private function onButtonClick(evt:KeyboardEvent):void
{
 var item:Object = evt.itemRenderer.data;
    openWorkflowItem(item.date.date, item.workFlowID);
    $multiEdit = false;

    if (target === currentWorkflowItems)
    {
        $histFilter['sym'] = item.sym;
        histSym.text = item.sym;
        applyHistFilters();
    }

}



<mx:AdvancedDataGrid
                    id="historicalWorkflowItems"
                    dataProvider="{$historicalWFItems}"
                    width="100%" height="100%"
                    itemClick="{onWFItemClick(event)}"
                    keyDown="if (event.keyCode==Keyboard.ENTER){ onButtonClick(event)}"
                    borderStyle="none"
                    sortExpertMode="true"
                    useHandCursor="true"
                    headerShift="{saveColumnSettings('historical', historicalWorkflowItems)}"
                    columnStretch="{saveColumnSettings('historical', historicalWorkflowItems)}"
                    horizontalScrollPolicy="auto"
                    verticalScrollPolicy="auto"
                    allowMultipleSelection="true"
                    >
```

Comment: `KeyboardEvent` does not have an `itemRenderer` property. Check to see what value `target` or `currentTarget` holds. Where do you add your keyboard listener?

Comment: i use this keyDown="if (event.keyCode==Keyboard.ENTER){ onButtonClick(event)}" within the advancedatagrid

Comment: Where? Post that code in your question, what you've provided so far is not enough for an answer.

Comment: What is `onButtonClick`?

Comment: The function above, although naming could be better (e.g onKeyHit)

Comment: @pconn222 Don't repost your question; edit the existing one instead.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are assigning a key listener to the grid, so there's no specific item in this context. The `keyDown` event fires whenever a key is pressed with focus *anywhere* within the grid. You want something like `itemKeyDown`, but the grid does not seem to provide you with such an event.

This is why I asked you to check `Event/target` to see what value it holds. If an item renderer has focus and the user presses a key, your handler will fire and you can check if the event `target` is an item renderer, ex `if(event.target is AdvancedDataGridItemRenderer)`. (The event `currentTarget` will always be the grid.) Now, I'm not super familiar with the implementation of `AdvancedDataGrid` item rendering, but it's likely that the event `target` will not itself be an item renderer, only a child of an item renderer (say a text field inside the item renderer). To check if the `target` is *inside* an item renderer is possible by walking the display tree and checking if a parent `is` an item renderer class:

```
function findItemRenderer(object:DisplayObject):AdvancedDataGridItemRenderer {
    var current:DisplayObject = object;
    while(current && !(current is AdvancedDataGrid)){
        if(current is AdvancedDataGridItemRenderer)
            return current as AdvancedDataGridItemRenderer;
        current = current.parent;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Now you can handle your event like this:

```
function gridKeyDown(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
    var item:AdvancedDataGridItemRenderer = findItemRenderer(e.target as DisplayObject);
    if(item){
        // do stuff with your item
    }
}
```

But this is getting kind of silly to search the display hierarchy like this. What you should do is just dispatch an event *from inside* your item renderer, so that the event target is always the item renderer itself. For example:

```
class MyItemRenderer extends AdvancedDataGridItemRenderer {
    public static const ITEM_ENTER:String = "itemEnter";
    public MyItemRenderer(){
        addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDown);
    }
    private function keyDown(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
        if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.ENTER)
            dispatchEvent(new Event(ITEM_ENTER, true)); // bubbles=true
    }
}
```

Now you can handle this event:

```
myGrid.addEventListener(MyItemRenderer.ITEM_ENTER, itemEnter);

function itemEnter(e:Event):void {
    var item:MyItemRenderer = e.target as MyItemRenderer;
    // do stuff with your item
}
```